# via terminal gdb is already codesigned

Tags: macos, gdb, lazarus

via terminal gdb is already codesigned but when i Run a project I get an error `,msg="Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 501: (os/kern) failure (0x5).\n (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))"`. I'm going mad. I've install gdb in folders `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin`. Also follow this instructions for certificates [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Codesigning-the-Debugger.html).But no good. WHAT DOES IT MEAN. please somebody

Comment: I also use `/usr/local/bin/gdb` in Debugger type and path

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow the instructions in that link exactly. You need to create a new certificate, make sure it exists in the System keychain and not the login one, and then run the task to codesign: `codesign -f -s "gdb-cert" /usr/local/bin/gdb`

To get this to work I also was *required* to restart my computer. Once I did that everything started working.